# How to find all values greater than 0 in a cell array in Matlab

Tags: matlab, operators, cell-array

I want to find and save all values greater than 0 in an array and save them in a variable called "times". How do I do that? And what is the difference between saving the indices of those cells versus the actual values of the cells?

This is what I have tried, but it must be worng because I get the error:

> Undefined operator '>' for input arguments of type
>   'cell'.

```
clear all, close all

[num,txt,raw] = xlsread('test.xlsx');

times = find(raw(:,5)>0)
```

Comment: what does `raw` look like? from the error, try `raw{:,5}`

Comment: Thanks @HBHB! I accepted the answer below though, because it was more detailed and was posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the **contents** of a cell you must use `{}` instead of `()`:

```
idx = find([raw{:, 5}] > 0);
```

But this gives you the **index** of the cells of `raw` containing a positive value. If you want the **values** instead, you can access them and collect them in a numeric array in this way:

```
times = [raw{idx, 5}];
```